# Double entry accounting engine

Tags: database, web-services, accounting

I'm looking for a *programmatic* double entry accounting system. I want to convert my web app to recording financial events via a web service, and rather than implement the generic double entry accounting logic myself, I'd like to use something that exists already to implement double entry accounting, and build my business logic on top of that.

To be clear: I am not looking for a service or software with a UI, unless it has a full API I can use instead of the UI.